# Render KaTeX inside a modal directly without an extra "click" inside the modal in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, katex

I am struggling ro render the `KaTeX` formulas inside my popups.
The `Javascript` function I'm using does this, but unfortunately only after i made a "click" inside of the generated popup.

And yes, sadly I have 0 knowledge in js and couldn't find an appropiate argument(?), which does render everything without the need to make a click somewhere.

**Here is an RME**:

```
renderKaTeX <- '
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("body").on("click", function() {
          var mathElements = document.getElementsByClassName("math");
          for(var i = 0; i < mathElements.length; i++) {
            renderMathInElement(
              mathElements[i], {
                delimiters: [{left: "$", right: "$", display: false}]
              });
          }
        });
 });
'

library(shiny)
library(shinyMobile)

shinyApp(
  ui = f7Page(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/katex.min.css", integrity="sha384-dbVIfZGuN1Yq7/1Ocstc1lUEm+AT+/rCkibIcC/OmWo5f0EA48Vf8CytHzGrSwbQ",crossorigin="anonymous"),
      tags$script(defer = "", src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/katex.min.js",integrity="sha384-2BKqo+exmr9su6dir+qCw08N2ZKRucY4PrGQPPWU1A7FtlCGjmEGFqXCv5nyM5Ij",crossorigin="anonymous"),
      tags$script(defer = "",src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js",integrity="sha384-kWPLUVMOks5AQFrykwIup5lo0m3iMkkHrD0uJ4H5cjeGihAutqP0yW0J6dpFiVkI",crossorigin="anonymous"),
      tags$script(HTML(renderKaTeX))
    ),
    title = "Popup",
    f7SingleLayout(
      navbar = f7Navbar(title = ""),
      f7Button("btn", "Open Popup")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$btn, {
      f7Popup(
        id = "popup1",
        title = "test",
        tags$div(class = "math",
                 tags$p("render me without click pls: $X$")         
        )
      )
    })
  }
)
```

It's probably just one argument I am missing, but still struggling since days on this matter.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **katex** package:

```r
library(katex)
library(shiny)
library(shinyMobile)

shinyApp(
  ui = f7Page(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/katex.min.css", integrity="sha384-dbVIfZGuN1Yq7/1Ocstc1lUEm+AT+/rCkibIcC/OmWo5f0EA48Vf8CytHzGrSwbQ",crossorigin="anonymous"),
      tags$script(defer = "", src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/katex.min.js",integrity="sha384-2BKqo+exmr9su6dir+qCw08N2ZKRucY4PrGQPPWU1A7FtlCGjmEGFqXCv5nyM5Ij",crossorigin="anonymous"),
      tags$script(defer = "",src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.1/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js",integrity="sha384-kWPLUVMOks5AQFrykwIup5lo0m3iMkkHrD0uJ4H5cjeGihAutqP0yW0J6dpFiVkI",crossorigin="anonymous")
    ),
    title = "Popup",
    f7SingleLayout(
      navbar = f7Navbar(title = ""),
      f7Button("btn", "Open Popup")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$btn, {
      f7Popup(
        id = "popup1",
        title = "test",
        tags$div(
          class = "math",
          tags$p(HTML(
            katex_html("\\int f = \\pi", displayMode = FALSE, preview = FALSE)
          ))         
        )
      )
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Is there any difference in using the package and creating the javascript functions manually? I have a lot of math stuff in my popups, so I have to call the function always, right? 

Like: text.....katex_html(...).......text.........and so forth